# How to drop columns with NA using cudf?

Tags: python, rapids, cudf

Pandas:

```
data = data.dropna(axis = 'columns')
```

I am trying to do something similar using a cudf dataframe but the apis don't offer this functionality.

My solution is to convert to a pandas df, do the above command, then re-convert to a cudf. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Apparently that feature is coming in a future release. That said, you can see the proposed method to accomplish it in the [github repo](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/pull/1126/files/b56bad7a4275189f556d1cb69b52879d94b1595b), and you may be able to repurpose this as a regular function instead of a class method to achieve the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cuDF now supports column based `dropna`, so the following will work:

```py
import cudf
​
df = cudf.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,None], 'b':[None,0,2], 'c':[1,2,3]})
print(df)
      a     b  c
0     0  null  1
1     1     0  2
2  null     2  3
```

```py
df.dropna(axis='columns')
    c
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Until `dropna` is implemented, you can check the `null_count` of each column and drop the ones with `null_count>0`.